# gitignore .o files in quickfix subdirectory

Tags: git

I'm trying to ignore all .o files in the quickfix subdirectory. The file is:

```
quickfix/examples/executor/C++/Application.o
```

I have tried the following:

```
**/quickfix/**o 
quickfix/*o     
quickfix/**/*o
```

EDIT: one option is to add a .gitignore file to the quickfix subdirectory with the *.o pattern. Does anyone know why the above patterns don't work?

Comment: Hm. gitignore(5) does not mention any special meaning of double-star, though there exist - seemingly faulty - websites that claims it does something. After all, gitignore(5) is rather clear on that its wildcards are interpreted according to fnmatch(3) rules, not zsh/rsync-style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gitignore` man page specifies how the patterns are matched. The relevant rule to your cases is:

> git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname.

So, `quickfix/*o` doesn't work because `*` won't match `/`. And `**` isn't recognized by `fnmatch` at all, and thus isn't recognized by Git, either.

Answer (score 5):

Make a new .gitignore in the quickfix directory with `*.o` in it. That will apply to the quickfix directory and all of its children.

> EDIT: one option is to add a .gitignore file to the quickfix subdirectory with the *.o pattern. Does anyone know why the above patterns don't work?

Lily Ballard's comment, as well as mipadi's answer explain it nicely.

Comment: Solves my problem - does anyone know why the patterns don't work though?

Comment: @Taras: Because git doesn't support the `**` glob extension, and without that there's no way to express what you want.